# Simple Perl module for accessing IRC servers

Tags: perl, cpan, irc

I'm trying to write an extremely simple IRC client which sets the topic on a given channel (for which it first needs to identify and gain ops). Ideally I want to be able to write something like this:

```
$client = new IRC::Client(%config);
$client->connect();
$client->identify('password');
$client->join('#channel');
$client->op('#channel'); # gain ops
$client->set_topic('#channel', 'new topic');
$client->disconnect();
```

Is there a module which supports this limited functionality, with a simple interface? All the IRC-related modules on metacpan seem to be aimed at people wanting to write fully functional bots - I've looked at [Bot::BasicBot](https://metacpan.org/module/Bot%3a%3aBasicBot), but that seems to want me to subclass the module, and [AnyEvent::IRC::Client](https://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aIRC%3a%3aClient) seems quite low level. I don't want to write event-handling code, just connect, issue a few commands, and disconnect.

Comment: how about `POE::Component::IRC`?

Comment: That seems overly complicated and low level for what I need - I don't even understand the code like $irc->yield( register => 'all' );.

Comment: `Net::IRC` looks quite simple, haven't used it before though

Comment: Unfortunately it's been deprecated since 2004.

Comment: IRC isn't the kind of protocol that you can do correctly without event-driven code. You need to be able to say "connect; when I get end-of-motd, identify. When I get successfully-identified, join. When I get joined, op up. When I get the mode line, change topic", etc.

Comment: I thought a module would do that for me - in the same way that I can do 'connect, when I get to end of MOTD, change directory, when I've changed directory, upload file' with the various FTP modules. In other words, I wouldn't expect the connect() method to return until it had finished - i.e. got to the end of the MOTD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider also [`Net::Async::IRC`](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aAsync%3a%3aIRC).